CORS issue with Azure AI search
I am trying make a easy demo with azure-search-openai-demo, For now, all I want is to make a new page with a button. When I press the button, it will run the indexer that I have set on the Azure portal.
The problem is that, I am keep getting the error like below which does not allowed me to do that on frontend even I am using the admin key.
Would be deeply appreciated if someone can help me with this.

Access to fetch at 'https://searchServiceName.search.windows.net/indexers/indexerName/run?api-version=2020-06-30' from origin 'http://127.0.0.1:50505' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.



import React from "react";
import { DefaultButton } from "@fluentui/react";
import styles from "./Helloworld.module.css"; 

const HelloWorld: React.FC = () => {
    // run indexer button
    // =========================================================
    const runIndexer = async () => {
        const indexerName = "xxx"; // indexer name
        const searchServiceName = "xxx"; // ai search service name
        const apiKey = "xxx"; // api key

        const url = `https://${searchServiceName}.search.windows.net/indexers/${indexerName}/run?api-version=2020-06-30`;

        await fetch(url, {
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
                "api-key": apiKey
            }
        });

        console.log(`Running Indexer ${indexerName} .....`);
    };

    return (
        <div className={styles.container}>
            <h1>Hello World</h1>
            <DefaultButton onClick={runIndexer} text="Run Indexer" className={styles.runIndexerButton} />
        </div>
    );
};

export default HelloWorld;




Does this answer your question? CORS issues on Azure Search Service

@Johannes Stadler, this one does not help. I've tried setting Allowed origin type to All or Custom. But it does not worked

@Dasari Kamali i am exactly using same backend and setting with azure-search-openai-demo(link above). All i do is just simply add a page and create a button

That's strange because it is the solution to the error message you posted. Did you try the "Custom" setting with http://127.0.0.1:50505?
To dig deeper into the issue you'll need to check if you're getting CORS headers back from the API. It could also be that it takes some time until the settings are reflected or browser caching kicks in here.

@Johannes Stadler, thx for the reply, unfortunately it does not work for me. Just wondering if i set it to All, it should be no difference.
